# Django CreateView with two forms at same page

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django and trying to display the detail of the person who has posted the data. So basically showing the username of the person who has posted the 'thing' defined in models.py

In views.py I'm trying:

```
def thing_detail_view(request, pk):
    thing_detail = Thing.objects.get(pk=pk)
    user = User.objects.get(request.user)
    return render(request, 'thing_detail.html', {'thing_detail': thing_detail, 'user': user})
```

Im getting error:

> 'User' object is not iterable

But I know I should not use request.user because thats basically means the user who is having current session or currently logged in. Any idea how can I get the username of the user who has posted the data of a particular 'pk' and show it in the html?

Comment: What does your `Thing` model definition look like? It needs a foreign key reference to the User model if you want to know who created it, using a line something like `created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)`. You can then access that user with `user = User.objects.get(id=thing_detail.created_by)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `userId = thing_detail.userId` instead of `request.user`

`userId` can be your primery key for User Model